# Why Fonts are rendering differently in Mac OS browsers although it renders correctly in Windows Browser?

Tags: css, iis, cross-browser, font-face

May I know why Fonts are rendering differently in Mac OS browsers although, it renders correctly in Windows Browser?
I search for it but I didn't get any solution.

Comment: Can you share some code please? Can we see your CSS? It is not easy to help without code and also please see >  How to ask a good question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the fonts available on the individual computer. If you specify Times New Roman and the OS doesn't have that font the browser must fall back to a standard serif font.

You can include a google font by linking to it in the head to allow the browser to download and display the font type.

See http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/working-with-typography/ and https://designshack.net/articles/css/a-beginners-guide-to-using-google-web-fonts/ for more information

Comment: I have deployed the application on Azure server and included fonts as well. Still fonts are not showing in the Mac OS.